# How to override the selected item style of MahApps Panorama Control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am using the `MahApps Panorama Control` in my project by linking the `Mahapps.Metro.dll` so I can't change the `XAML-Code` of the `Panorama Control` directly.
I thought it would be possible to override values in my `MainWindow.xaml` but when I do so nothing changes or maybe I change the wrong property.

The problem with the `Panorama Control` is that the selected item has a white border and I can't find a way to remove this selection style. I tried several solutions like changing the [style](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1e3d6032-32a8-491d-945d-75ce5e4379b7) or changing the control template ([How to disable highlighting on listbox but keep selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343793/how-to-disable-highlighting-on-listbox-but-keep-selection)) but my changes have no influence of the `Panorama Control`.

There you can see the [Panorama Control XAML](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/Panorama.xaml).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the way that the Styles are inherited, and it's tricky to see how the ListViewItems and ListBoxItems work together. I fixed this by inserting the following in the code behind. It does, however, lose your selected item:

```
var listbox = MyPanorama.FindChildByType<ListBox>();
if (listbox != null)
{
    listbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

FindChildByType is a simple search to return the first ListBox that is found under the Panorama. If you have a search by name the x:Name of the template listbox is "items".