# How to display a list of windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm attempting to write a program, part of which will display a list of open windows (or more specifically, their names or titles)

So the XAML for the view looks like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Windows}" />
```

and the `ViewModel` class looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Window> Windows { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
  this.Windows = new ObservableCollection<Window>();
  this.Windows.Add(new Window());
}
```

This causes the program (and the designer view) to throw `InvalidOperationException: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.`

It seems that the problem is that the `ItemsControl` thinks I actually want to add the `Window` itself as a control rather than as a class (where I would expect the window to show the text `System.Windows.Window` or something similar).

I've tried adding `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate>...`, but this seems to have the same result.

Finally, I've tried creating a dummy `WindowHolder` class with a single public property of a `Window`. That seems to work, but seems a really inelegant way of doing things where it feels like it should be simpler.

### tl;dr

The question is "How can you simply (preferably in XAML) display a list of window titles on a WPF `ItemsControl`, bound to an `ObservableCollection<Window>` in the view model?

Comment: I suspect you've already got the best approach - it sounds like WPF doesn't like populating an `ItemsControl` with a ref to an element which already exists further up the visual tree (I can imagine that some craziness could result if you pointed to the `Content` property of the `Window` objects in that collection if this was allowed...think infinitely recursive visual tree!). The simplest solution is to create a wrapper which you've already done.

Comment: @Charleh You might want to put that down as an answer. If no-one comes back with an alternative view I'll mark yours as the correct one.

Comment: Did you just want the window titles ? Or an actual Window

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis I just want to display some property/properties of the window. Things like the Name, Title, Dimensions, for example. I don't want to try to display the actual window contents themselves.

Comment: @PhilipC If you just want to display properties of a Window, why do you need a Window Control for?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis It's not that I *need* a Window control, it's that I have a collection of Window controls and I want to show some of their properties in a list.

Comment: Can you not just create a Model (WindowProperties.cs) that wraps the Window's properties that you need and don't use that collection of Windows as your ItemsSource but instead the Collection of a Model with the properties that you want to display and do the binding.

Comment: Since you don't need to show the Window at all, you might not see right now the performance hit you are going to get in the future once the collection gets bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ListBox` instead of `ItemsControl`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Windows}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The issue is that the default behavior for adding controls into a generic `ItemsControl` causes the `ContentPresenter` to be wrapped in the control itself. So your collection `Windows` will want to be added as containers to the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsPresenter`, but it fails for the reason described in the exception. `ListBox` works because the wrapping containers are `ListBoxItems`, not `Windows`. In order to provide support for `Window` in an `ItemsControl` you would have to implement your own custom control for `ItemsControl` to return a container that isn't a `Window`.

Comment: This does make the problem I'm having go away, and I don't think having them selectable should cause any real problems. It seems strange that `ListBox` can cope where `ItemsControl` can't...

Comment: @Philip You can set the style to do this, I'll add the code from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343793/how-to-disable-highlighting-on-listbox-but-keep-selection)

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thank you very much. I'll leave the question open for a few days to see if any other ideas come in, but at the minute I think you're winning :P

Comment: This must be a control template difference since `ListBox` inherits `ItemsControl` - it would be interesting to see the difference in implementation between the two. Good knowledge to have though!

Comment: @Philip See my updated answer as the reason why you can't use a generic ItemsControl for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've already got the best approach - it sounds like WPF doesn't like populating an `ItemsControl` with a reference to an element which already exists further up the visual tree.

The visual tree must check references, because I've tested this by creating a wrapper class which has a ref to the `Window` and then used an `ItemsControl` to display the content of that window (to see if I could make it explode!) and it gave the following error:

`Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree. This could indicate a cycle in the tree.`

Which is an infinitely recursive tree

So in summary the simplest solution seems to be to create a wrapper for the properties that you want (which you've already done) and avoid referencing ancestor elements in leaf/child nodes!

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct, you need to create an ItemTemplate for the ItemsControl. Each item in the ItemsControl will be of Type Window and you need to expose the Title property in the template

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBlock Text={Binding Title}/>
</DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I had already tried this approach, and it results in the same exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Well what I would do is the following:

- Create an Interface wrapper(as already stated) for window ie IWindow with Title property.
- All Windows would implement IWindow
- Make an Observable collection of IWindow instead of Window.

Comment: I'd suspect this would have the same issue as technically a ref to `IWindow` would still be a ref to `Window` and I've got a feeling that the visual tree would know! Worth a try though

Comment: Just tested (this new laptop is FAST!), and as I suspected; this doesn't work. The `IWindow` is still really a ref to `Window` and the visual tree knows this :(