# ListBox Item style not being applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a style for my ListBoxItem, however the style is not being applied.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

**Code:**

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource MyListStyle}" Content="Test1" Foreground="Gray"/>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource MyListStyle}" Content="Test2" Foreground="Gray"/>
</ListBox>
```

**Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="MyListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because WPF properties is listed from highest to lowest precedence

So your ListBoxItem.Foreground is local setting, highest than other

```
 <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource MyListStyle}" Content="Test2" Foreground="Gray"/>
```

You can remove

```
<ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource MyListStyle}" Content="Test2"/>
```

And set Foreground in StaticResource style

```
<Style x:Key="MyListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

You can find precedence list in [wpf.2000things](https://wpf.2000things.com/2010/11/22/133-where-a-dependency-property-gets-its-value/)

And MSDN [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: just another question, how to remove this blue effect from the box? what name of this property

Comment: Try <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/> in your MyListStyle StaticResource

Comment: the blue box still appears

Comment: So ListBox default style not blue, is defined ListBox style anywhere?

Comment: Yes I already created the style and added, Foreground is working only this blue border when you select that I can't remove

Comment: Ok I see, you want to remove selection highlight, answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343793/how-to-disable-highlighting-on-listbox-but-keep-selection