# How to hide hover and click event of UniformGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listboxitem

I try to create a list of buttons with two columns using a `ListBox` and `UniformGrid`. Everything seemed to be okay until I faced the following issue. The margin space of the button was shown with light blue color when I click it or hover over it. How to remove this effect?

[image: ListBox with custom data template applied that conatins a Button. On click, the button of an item is surrounded by a blue border with light blue background.]

This is my code:

```
<ListBox Width="1000" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Name="uniformGrid1" Margin="50" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemsList}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" Background="Transparent"   Name="uniformGrid1"></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Margin="50" Height="70" Click="keyword_Click" Width="250"
         Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Helvetica Neue" FontWeight="Bold"
        BorderBrush="SlateGray" Content="{Binding Name}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.073" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9F9" Offset="0.571" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD7D7EC" Offset="0.243" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item in the `ItemsSource` is wrapped in a [`ListBoxItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listboxitem?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) inside the [`ListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). A `ListBox` is a control derived from [`Selector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which is a base type for items controls that allow selection of items.

> Represents a control that allows a user to select items from among its child elements.

What you specified as `DataTemplate` will be placed in a `ListBoxItem` at runtime, which is the container for the content. This container has a [default style and control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#listboxitem-parts) that defines its appearance and visual states. What you see is the *MouseOver* state and the *Selected* state. You can change this by [extracting the default style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825030/6181599) for `ListBoxItem` and adapting it or by writing your own.

- [How to create a template for a control (WPF.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-template?view=netdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0)

However, it seems that your intention is different. What you probably wanted was to simply display buttons in a `UniformGrid` depending on a bound collection, without any selection. You can achieve this by using an `ItemsControl` instead. It does not offer any selection capabilities, but lets you bind a collection with the `UniformGrid` as items panel.

```
<ItemsControl Width="1000" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Margin="50" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemsList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" Background="Transparent" Name="uniformGrid1"></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Margin="50" Height="70" Click="keyword_Click" Width="250"
         Foreground="Black" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Helvetica Neue" FontWeight="Bold"
        BorderBrush="SlateGray" Content="{Binding Name}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.073" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9F9" Offset="0.571" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFD7D7EC" Offset="0.243" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Please note that I have removed one of two `Name="uniformGrid1"` as duplicate names lead to a compilation error. If your content exceeds the viewport and you need scrollbars, you have to add a `ScrollViewer`, since this is built into the `ListBox`, but not the `ItemsControl`.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <ItemsControl  Width="1000" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Margin="50" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItemsList}">
      <!-- ...other code. -->
   </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `ListBox` has a selection, and selected items get highlighted. You need to disable this highlighting to get the desired result, for example by setting `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343793/how-to-disable-highlighting-on-listbox-but-keep-selection). This will remove the (lightblue) selection color.